# CONV() function in snowflake

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to find equivalent of the `CONV()` MySQL function in Snowflake, but I can't seem find it.

I'm trying to do the following in Snowflake:

`SELECT CONV('39ix75wf3aor7',36,10)`

The result should be `15468921890196183763`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a UDF to do what CONV() does. It works, but unfortunately Javascript variables don't support numeric precision for as large as your sample.

This will work for smaller inputs, but for your large Base36 input the following happens:

15468921890196183763 --should be this result

15468921890196185000 --Javascript native variables do not have that level of precision

In case you find it useful for smaller values to covert from one base to another, here it is:

```
create or replace function CONV(VALUE_IN string, OLD_BASE float, NEW_BASE float)
returns string
language javascript
as
$$
    // Usage note: Loses precision for very large inputs
    return parseInt(VALUE_IN, Math.floor(OLD_BASE).toString(Math.floor(NEW_BASE)));
$$;
```

Comment: thank you this worked! Went back to my table and realized that the IDs that I needed to convert to base 10 could handle the conversion as they werent as large as the example i provided.