# Convert a column from Base 36 to base 10 using snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to convert two or three columns in a huge table from base 36 to base 10.

I know the python code for it. But looking to do it in SQL (Snowflake). Is there a better way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568668/base-36-to-base-10-conversion-using-sql-only

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CONV() function in snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60347914/conv-function-in-snowflake)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a JavaScript UDF to convert from any base to another base. Just call CONV(x, 36, 10) to go from base 36 to base 10.

[CONV() function in snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60347914/conv-function-in-snowflake)